# Create a link to full-sized image attachment?

Tags: images

I'm using some transitional css to "slide" up a div (".mask") which contains a short excerpt of the post when you hover over the post thumbnail.

This works very well, but I'd also like to add a text or icon link to each "mask" div which will link directly to the full size version of the image (and hopefully open automatically in fancybox).

Here's the code I'm using so far - thanks

```
<div class="main">
<div class="view view-first">
<h4><a href="<?php  the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
<div class="myimage">
<?php tt_thumb(300,185); ?>
</div>

<div class="mask">
<?php the_content_limit($hp_mid_content_length,''); 
?>
</div> </div> </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if TimThumb is really necessary. You could easily do that with internal WordPress functions.
Add this code to your functions.php:

```
<?php
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); // this enable thumbnails
add_image_size( 'preview-thumb', 300, 185, true ); //this sets your default size
?>
```

Use the following code instead of your code above.

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="view view-first">
    <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
    <div class="myimage">
      <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail())
        {
          $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'preview-thumb' );
          echo '<img src="' . $thumb[0] . '">';
        } else {
          echo 'No post thumbnail.';
        }
      ?>
    </div>
    <div class="mask">
      <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail())
        {
          $full = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'full' );
          echo '<a href="' . $full[0] . '">Some text.</a>';
        } else {
          echo 'No post thumbnail.';
        }
        the_content_limit($hp_mid_content_length,'');
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then follow [these steps](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails#Setting_a_Post_Thumbnail) to add a post thumbnail.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I had already tried the standard codex suggestions. Perhaps what I am struggling with is incorporating this into my existing code, as I am unsure how or where to add it. I would like to add a new link - either text or a grahic / icon to the mask div to open the attachment image directly...

Comment: Just add the code above into you div with the class "mask".

Comment: Yeah - tried that but it doesn't make any difference. I don't even see "some text"? If the mods allow, I can add a temporary link to the test site if that might help?

Comment: Do you use this code within the loop? I added an 'else' statement to my code, does it output 'No post thumbnail.'? If yes, you did not set a post thumbnail. And remember: To enable post thumbnails, the current theme must include add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); in its functions.php file. See also [the WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails).

Comment: I updated the answer. Please try that.

Comment: Really appreciate your efforts, but results in 6 no thumbnails found :(

Comment: Added featured image to first post & that appears to be working as intended?

Comment: Marking this as resolved as I can work around with featured images. But if you or anyone else can suggest a way to make it work with just the first image found in a post that would be excellent - thanks for your help / patience!

Comment: Yeah, I thought you meant the featured image (= post thumbnail). I did not test this, but [this](http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2010/04/19/wordpress-plugin-automatic-post-thumbnail/) is a plugin which does exactly what you want. Glad I could help you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The way I read your question I believe you're after wp_get_attachment_link.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link

Comment: Lone link is considered a poor answer (see [help > deleted answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.